# Bash - how to append a newline after lines starting with the same letter?

Tags: bash, cygwin, newline, alphabetical

I have a file with, let's say, the following lines:

```
alibi
all
bone
chair
clever
cup
curse
dog
donut
```

I want to add a newline after the last word that starts with the same letter; that is, I want the output to be:

```
alibi
all

bone

chair
clever
cup
curse

dog
donut
```

Is there any way to do it? I'm not an expert so I don't even know where to start for this one. I prefer it to be a one-liner, too.

I'm working in Windows environment Cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a one-line `awk` command that does what I'm looking for:

```
awk '{if ( substr ($0, 0, 1) != prev) print "\n"$0; else print $0; prev = substr ($0, 0, 1)}'
```

This answer was adapted from a one-liner from http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/kurse/pmaier/Korpus/DataIntensiveLinguistics/node40.html.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line, remember the first character of the word, compare with the first character of the next one.

```
#!/bin/bash

prev=''
while read word ; do
    char=${word:0:1}
    if [[ $prev && $prev != $char ]] ; then
        echo
    fi
    prev=$char
    echo "$word"
done < input-file
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I think I found a shorter solution!